# Substitution of org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addFilterDefinition(FilterDefinition definition) in Hibernate5.x

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate 3.x, there is a method addFilterDefinition(FilterDefinition definition) of class org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration. But in Hibernate 5.x, this addFilterDefinition(FilterDefinition definition) method is removed from Configuration class as AnnotationConfiguration is depricated.

What will be the code substitution in Hibernate-5.x?

Please help on this migration issue.